# Как сделать одностороннее столкновение с коллайдером в 2D платформере?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется 2D платформер. Сверху платформ есть физическая полоска `Edge Collider 2D`, а на персонаже `Box Collider 2D`. Когда персонаж стоит снизу и подпрыгивает, он бьется головой о полоску. Как сделать так, чтобы прыгая снизу он ее пролетал насквозь, а при приземлении становился сверху?

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Поменяйте `Edge Collider 2D` на `Box Collider 2D` - в нем есть  `Used by Effector` - нужно его включить. Затем добавьте `PlatformEffector2D`.  Настраивайте его как хотите, и теперь персонаж "пропрыгивает" платформу снизу-вверх

Comment: Забыл напомнит, что надо будет у  `Edge Collider 2D` не забыть нажать галочку `Used By Effector`. Добавил это уточнение в ответ тоже

Comment: @KremSoda у `Edge Collider 2D` тоже есть галка `Used By Effector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Один из вариантов — использовать **[Physics.IgnoreCollision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html)**. `IgnoreCollision` устанавливает флаг `ignore` в  `true` или `false` и тем самым может контролировать игнорирование одним коллайдером другого.

Как пример. У тебя есть платформа. У этой платформы можно установить триггер. выглядит это примерно так:

```
   ___________
   | platform|
 ---------------
 | |_________| |
 |   trigger   |
 ---------------
```

Теперь в скрипте платформы добавь метод `OnTriggerEnter`, в котором когда персонаж будет входить в него ты будешь включать игнорирование в `Physics.IgnoreCollision`, делая так, чтобы персонаж игнорировал платформу. А когда персонаж покидает триггер (OnTriggerExit), тог используй `Physics.IgnoreCollision` снова, установив флаг в `false`, чтобы  сделать возможность персонажа сталкиваться с платформой опять.

---

Второй вариант — посмотреть в сторону компонента **[PlatformEffector2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlatformEffector2D.html)**, который вроде как позволяет задать только одну сторону для коллизии. Добавляешь компонент на платформу и регулируешь.

Помимо этого у `Edge Collider 2D` надо не забыть нажать галочку `Used By Effector`.